# Calling ajax function as a variable declared in asp.net master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to set some session variables using Ajax function call. The function is declared as a variable in ASP.Net master page since it will have to be called from different pages.

In response to a drop down selection change I call this function and since I need to wait until it has done its work before using some f the values I used $.when. But the function is hit after drop down selection change event is completed. I guess this is how asp.net orders function executions (main page before master page). Any idea how to resolve this? I need to be able to call this from any other page, hence adding it to master page.

I tried taking it out of master page and put it in a separate js file and include the file, but that didn't help either, same thing happens: page first, js is run after which is too late.

This is in master page:

```
setISCSession = function(isc) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/WebService/idc.asmx/SetISCSessionVars",
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify({ ISC: isc }),
    }).done(function (result) {debugger
        if (!result || result.d === "" || result.d.length == 0) {
        }
        else {
            var iscData = JSON.parse(result.d)[0];
            siteTZ = iscData.SITE_TZ;
            utcOffset = iscData.UTC_OFFSET;
            ...
            // this is just window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, value)
            $.session.set('Site_TZ', siteTZ);
            $.session.set('UTC_Offset', utcOffset);
            ...
        }
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
        alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
```

In some page:

```
$(document).on('change', '#ddlSelISC', function () {debugger
    isc = $(this).val();
    $.when(setISCSession(isc))
        .done(function (r1) {debugger
            var tz = $.session.get('Site_TZ');
            $('#hfSiteTZ').val(tz);
            $('#lblOffset').text($.session.get('UTC_Offset'));
            ...
        });
});
```

Comment: You forgot to return `$.ajax()` from `setISCSeccion`. Currently there's no promise being passed to `$.when` so it's invoked immediately. `return $.ajax({ ...`

Comment: I added return but now when I inspect "r1", it shows as undefined.